# How to split string at a specific char(set of chars, actually), but with specified length

Tags: python, string, split, delimiter

I'm pretty sure that there's such question..

Here's the issue - I want to split a string, using some specified chars as delimiters, but I also want the substrings to have length, close to the specified.

---

Real world example - split long subtitles lines.

Example:

```
1234,asd dsa qwerty 567,
```

I want to split the line to a number of lines with max length, let's say 10, but I don't want to "split" words. So, this should become:

```
1234,asd
dsa qwerty 
567,
```

---

Of course, I can split the lines by delimiters and then concatenate them again, till I reach the desired length, but this will be terribly slow.

I thought about using `str.find` (and use the returned position) but it can't work with regex (because of the different delimiters - `.`, `,`, `;`, `\n`, , etc.).

I think about `re.findall`, but I can't think of an regex. I thought something about something like

```
(.*){, max_len}\s
```

with `re.S`, but it's obviously not working. There should be some tricky way..

Comment: I means that it doesn't match what I want to match. I guess it's because the `{ , max_len }` matches repeating of the whole group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code splits your string as desired at spaces with a width of 10:

```
import re
r = "1234,asd dsa qwerty 567,"
p = re.compile("(.{,10})($|\s)")
r = p.sub("\\1\n", r)
```

In this case it produces output

```
1234,asd
dsa qwerty
567,
```

when split with width 5 you get

```
1234,asd
dsa
qwerty
567,
```

You can see, that words are never split with this method.

If you like other delimiters just replace "\s" with the desired regular expression.

Comment: Ha, now I see your edit - yes, I can use `[delimiters]` here, instead of just `\s`, I can also use different "new line char", not just `\n`. Great (:

Comment: hm, no.. interesting. This splits more than I want. `s = "asd asd"` will be split, and there's no need. Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: The way I do it now is - use `splitlines`, because the string could have more than on line and then iterate through the lines and use this split. Then use `''.join`, but this is slow, again. Better idea?

Comment: @Kiril Kirov You can use "(.{,10})($|\s)" to handle also this case properly.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [1]: import textwrap

In [2]: textwrap.wrap('1234,asd dsa qwerty 567,', 10)
Out[2]: ['1234,asd', 'dsa qwerty', '567,']
```

Comment: But this way, if you use `5` as length for splitting, you'll get substrings `dsa q` and `werty` which splits the word `qwerty`

Comment: if you pass  `break_long_words=False` to `textwrap.wrap`, it won't break words across lines.